# Centering Text in QTableWidgetItem during cell Edit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

The following PyQt4 example demonstrates my problem.  The text in the QTableWidget cells is centered nicely, until you edit the cells.  When you edit a cell the text is left justified.

I would like to maintain center alignment during edit of each cell.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import Qt
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(parent=self)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setRowCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['col1','col2'])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['row1','row2'])

        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('x')
        item.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter|Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, item)

        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('x')
        item.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter|Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, item)

        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('x')
        item.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter|Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table.setItem(1, 0, item)

        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('x')
        item.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter|Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table.setItem(1, 1, item)

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Plastique")   # set style
    myapp = MainWindow()      # instantiate the main window
    myapp.show()              # show the main window
    rc = app.exec_()
    myapp.close()
    sys.exit(rc)   # exit with the same return code of Qt application
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to implement a delegate:

```
class CenterDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)
        editor.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        return editor
```

And then you set it to the `QTableWidget`:

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(parent=self)
delegate = CenterDelegate()
self.table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc.  Quick, concise, brilliant.